# Nginx config rewriting subdomain name to 1st URI segment

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, subdomain, configuration

I'm unable to do the following nginx.conf rewrite:

```
test.mysite.info
```

to:

```
mysite.info/test
```

here's what i've tried:

```
server {
  server_name test.mysite.info;
  rewrite ^  https://mysite.info/test/$request_uri;
}
```

I know my DNS (Route53 AWS) is correct b/c:

1. test.mysite.info redirects to mysite.info (just not mysite.info/test)
2. I have an Apache server handling mysite.**com** which using .htaccess I can rewrite `test.mysite.com` to `mysite.com/test`.

I haven't changed anything else from the default nginx.conf installation so I'm totally confused as to why such a simple thing isn't working. Here is [my full nginx.conf file](https://gist.github.com/3517383) if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to specify a [listen](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name test.mysite.info;
    rewrite     ^ https://mysite.info/test$request_uri;
}
```

But wait, [`return`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) may be better than [`rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name test.mysite.info;
    return      301 https://mysite.info/test$request_uri;
}
```